# Using arbitrary smbserver on port 445

Tags: python, windows, smb

I want to write a totally arbitrary SMB server on my computer.

I'm using Impact (http://code.google.com/p/impacket/source/browse/trunk/impacket/smbserver.py), but the problem (probably) is I can't listen to port 445, as it is already in use by windows.

I've killed the LanmanServer service, but it didn't help.

Running `netstat -a` I can clearly see port 445 is still in used.

Using CurrPorts I can see that the process that is listening to this port is PID 4 (a.k.a. `System` process) but obviously I can't (and don't want to) kill it.

On the other hand, just for the sake of it, I've tried to listen to some random port (5002), and check out the SMB server by connecting to `\\[my internal ip = 10.0.0.4]:5002\`, weirdly enough, this also didn't work out.

I could see some request in Wireshark.. and I know my python process was listening to this port, but it just didn't answer.

On the server I just run this:

```
SMBSERVER(('10.0.0.4', 5002))
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/629648/how-to-disable-feature-that-opened-port-445-on-windows-server

Comment: Off topic as it asks how to disable the windows feature that listens on 445.